# Javascript Dropdown Menu - Refresh when the selection is changed

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, html.dropdownlistfor

I am trying to set this up so that when a user changes the 'hier_start', the page is refreshed and the dropdown is preselected with the selection that was just made.

```
<form name='categories' id="categories">
<div class="row">
    <select name="hier_start" onchange="javascript: NextCat('A', this.value)">
    <option value="0" parent="0">Select...</option>
    [% FOREACH hier_start IN categories.keys %]
    <option value="[% hier_start %]">[% hier_start %]</option>
    [% END %]
    </select>
    <select name="hier_A" style="display:none" onchange="javascript: NextCat('B', this.value)">
    <option value="0" parent="0">Select...</option>
    </select>
    <select name="hier_B" style="display:none" onchange="javascript: NextCat('C', this.value)">
    <option value="0" parent="0">Select...</option>
    </select>
    <select name="hier_C" style="display:none" onchange="javascript: NextCat('D', this.value)">
    <option value="0" parent="0">Select...</option>
    </select>
    <select name="hier_D" style="display:none">
    <option value="0" parent="0">Select...</option>
    </select>

</div>
```

Comment: What templating language/schema are you using? `[% FOREACH hier_start IN categories.keys %]`

Answer (score 2):

The onchange attribute should only contain the action to perform:

```
<select name="hier_start" onchange="javascript: NextCat('A', this.value)">
```

should be

```
<select name="hier_start" onchange="NextCat('A', this.value)">
```

I don't see any details as to your approach for refreshing the page, so I cannot provide any insight on that other than you probably don't need to refresh the page at all.

Comment: Thanks for your answer -- however the reason for the refresh is because hier_A needs to be cleared upon selecting a different hier_Start...and it seems like a simple refresh will do this.

Comment: What do you mean by 'cleared'? Do you need to toss all the option children elements?

Comment: Actually my initial posting was incorrect. It does not need to reload with the value preselected, it can simply refresh with all dropdown menus cleared. Yes, toss all options for ALL elements

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a server side language (PHP, ASP, etc) or cookies to send the values. There might be a way of doing it by replacing the html without refreshing the page (which I don't recommend) but this disappears when the page is reloaded again since it loads the original .html file.

Comment: Actually my initial posting was incorrect. It does not need to reload with the value preselected, it can simply refresh with all dropdown menus cleared.

Comment: Then you can put something in javascript function you are calling. For this select box                                            `code` <select name="hier_A" id="hier_A" style="display:none" onchange="javascript: NextCat('B', this.value)">
    <option value="0" parent="0">Select...</option>
    </select> `code` You will have in javascript function something like `code` document.getElementById("hier_A").selectedIndex="None"; `code` which will make it go back to default value.